# Category Listing Page with posts filtered to selected tag on Wordpress Blog

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm working on a Wordpress 3.4 project. I have categories and then several tags, and also one custom taxonomy as types.

Wordpress is fantastic as far as it handles all the taxonomy page, but I'm unable to figure out how to have pages where I have categories listing page (with pagination) specifically filtered to a selected tag or custom taxonomy.

So basically I want Categories, but then again, I also need to have a categories page with all posts filtered to specific tag, and then with pagination.

I have tried to figure out how to do that, but unable to find the exact doc or help. The issue is also with the URL, as how it will be formed?

Any idea how to fix that one, or any plugin to get this things done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think these two codex pages will help you along your way.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query
and
http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png

You can use WP_Query to query posts based on tags and categories/custom taxonomies and much more.

If you look at the template hierarchy you'll see you can use special template files for tags and taxonomies too. Just remember to flush your permalinks if you're not seeing these templates being used if you create one.